# Uniq 16 digit random number in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to generate uniq number of 16 digit in ruby

I am using this

```
SecureRandom.random_number(10**10).to_s.rjust(16,'0')
```

Is this right ?

or it will repeate same number any point.

Comment: What do you mean by **uniq** here? Unique as in uuid?

Comment: There's a one in 10^10 chance that will repeat. If that isn't enough use a larger range. For something very unlikely to repeat consider using a 64-bit random value, or a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

Answer (score 1):

To make your number "more random", you should rather use

```
SecureRandom.random_number(10**16).to_s.rjust(16,'0')
```

Whether this is "right" or not would depend on the particular use case, which is not specified in your question.

Note that you would get the same number after 10**16 calls (or earlier), there's no way you can avoid that.